# WordPress Comments Sorting

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is it possible to display comments in a manner that they group by user role. For example, all comments made by subscribers show first, then all comments made by non-users show.

Comment: Everything is possible, so to answer your question : Yes. You could try to do it, then once you have some very specific problem, ask them on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by default in WP without custom coding.